# Arithmetic? Logical/Boolean/Bitwise operations?

Tags: arithmetic

I'm trying to convey to some folks some logical and bitwise operators such as AND, OR, XOR, &c in programming languages such as C &| Java.  Though these I guess could be considered "boolean" operators there is no "Boolean Algebra" in here, just the results of various operation, yes?

I've never heard of Boolean **Arithmetic**, but would one consider these simple questions

`5 AND 8 = ?`

boolean arithmetic (operating bitwise) or rather *logical* or *bitwise* arithmetic?

Comment: What is algebra (or arithmetic) other than the results of various operations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The terms *boolean*, *binary*, and *bitwise* arithmetic are all equivalent in my mind. However, it is most commonly referred to as *binary arithmetic* in my experience.

[*Boolean algebra*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28logic%29) however is a more general field (encompassing more than just arithmetic), and is really synonymous for *classical propositional calculus*.

Answer (score 7):

But there is boolean algebra here. Namely, you can consider an $\rm n$-bit integer as a characteristic function for a subset of $\rm\: n = \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$, viz. bit $\rm i$ of $\rm k$ is $1$ iff $\rm i$ lies in the subset represented by $\rm k$. The bitwise boolean operations suffice to define all of the boolean algebra operations in this powerset boolean algebra.

Comment: The whole explanation went above my head, can you please explain it in some detail. For example recently I was trying to solve $$1010 \text{ OR } 0011$$ though I can solve it bitwise but is there any other insight to be gained from it?